# What are the most hardcore optimisations you've seen?

Tags: optimization

I'm not talking about algorithmic stuff (eg use quicksort instead of bubblesort), and I'm not talking about simple things like loop unrolling.

I'm talking about the *hardcore* stuff. Like [Tiny Teensy ELF](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html), [The Story of Mel](http://catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html); practically everything in the demoscene, and so on.

Comment: Those links are great - I've not seem them before. +1

Comment: You should probably make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 29):

I once wrote a brute force RC5 key search that processed two keys at a time, the first key used the integer pipeline, the second key used the SSE pipelines and the two were interleaved at the instruction level. This was then coupled with a supervisor program that ran an instance of the code on each core in the system. In total, the code ran about 25 times faster than a naive C version.

Comment: Impressive. But I feel sorry for whoever has to maintain it (but that's the nature of super-optimized code).

Comment: I'm the maintainer, it was a pet project. It is well commented, and I placed the code for the two pipelines in their own columns to make it easier to follow.

Comment: "I placed the code for the two pipelines in their own columns to make it easier to follow" - great idea. I imagine that would have never crossed my mind.

Comment: Yeah, same... That's actually quite brilliant.

Comment: I would give you +2 if I could: one for the code, and another for the two-column-code. Brilliant^2!

Comment: "Faster than the native C version"  so what did you write it in?

Comment: If you used SSE, how about using the GPU in addition to that?

Comment: @Neil N: I wrote the key processing in pure assembler with a C++ interface for handling threading.
@LiraNuna: Yes, you might be able to use the GPU, this was written a while ago before GPGPUs were common.

Answer (score 16):

In one (here unnamed) video game engine I worked with, they had rewritten the model-export tool (the thing that turns a [Maya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Maya) mesh into something the game loads) so that instead of just emitting data, it would actually emit the exact stream of microinstructions that would be necessary to render that particular model. It used a genetic algorithm to find the one that would run in the minimum number of cycles. That is to say, the data format for a given model was actually a perfectly-optimized subroutine for rendering just that model. So, drawing a mesh to the screen  meant loading it into memory and branching into it.

(This wasn't for a PC, but for a console that had a vector unit separate and parallel to the CPU.)

Comment: This is getting more common among console games as the consoles often have a command buffer that is used to actually render graphics, thus it is just easier to precalculate the required commands and then send them straight to the graphics card (in addition to any pointer fixups needed).

Answer (score 10):

In the early days of DOS when we used floppy discs for all data transport there were viruses as well.  One common way for viruses to infect different computers was to copy a virus bootloader into the bootsector of an inserted floppydisc.  When the user inserted the floppydisc into another computer and rebooted without remembering to remove the floppy, the virus was run and infected the harddrive bootsector, thus permanently infecting the host PC.  A particulary annoying virus I was infected by was called "Form", to battle this I wrote a custom floppy bootsector that had the following features:

- Validate the bootsector of the host harddrive and make sure it was not infected.
- Validate the floppy bootsector and
  make sure that it was not infected.
- Code to remove the virus from the
  harddrive if it was infected.
- Code to duplicate the antivirus
  bootsector to another floppy if a
  special key was pressed.
- Code to boot the harddrive if all was
  well, and no infections was found.

This was done in the program space of a bootsector, about 440 bytes :)

The biggest problem for my mates was the very cryptic messages displayed because I needed all the space for code.  It was like "FFVD RM?", which meant "FindForm Virus Detected, Remove?"

I was quite happy with that piece of code.  The optimization was program size, not speed.  Two quite different optimizations in assembly.

Answer (score 9):

My favorite is the floating point inverse square root via integer operations. This is a cool little hack on how floating point values are stored and can execute faster (even doing a 1/result is faster than the stock-standard square root function) or produce more accurate results than the standard methods.

In c/c++ the code is: (sourced from Wikipedia)

```
float InvSqrt (float x)
{
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    int i = *(int*)&x;
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);   // Now this is what you call a real magic number
    x = *(float*)&i;
    x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: And these days we can just call __frsqrte. It's too easy; we've all gone soft!

Comment: is "__frsqrte" the assembly instruction for the square root? because i have read that InvSqrt(n) is 4 times faster then 1/sqrt(n) (assuming that sqrt uses the FSQRT assembly instruction). But still I am soft... i would not care about that 4 times performance diference... :/

Comment: I ran a bunch of timings on invsqrts ( http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/2009/10/16/timing-square-root/ ). The short story is that `_frsqrte` -- the SSE *scalar* op for an estimated inverse square root -- is four times faster than InvSqrt(), which is six times faster than 1.0/`FSQRT`. On the PowerPC the situation is different; there, InvSqrt() is a total disaster because of a load-hit-store issue.

Answer (score 7):

### A Very Biological Optimisation

**Quick background:** Triplets of DNA nucleotides (A, C, G and T) encode amino acids, which are joined into proteins, which are what make up most of most living things.

Ordinarily, each different protein requires a separate sequence of DNA triplets (its "gene") to encode its amino acids -- so e.g. 3 proteins of lengths 30, 40, and 50 would require 90 + 120 + 150 = 360 nucleotides in total.  However, in viruses, space is at a premium -- so **some viruses overlap the DNA sequences for different genes**, using the fact that there are 6 possible "reading frames" to use for DNA-to-protein translation (namely starting from a position that is divisible by 3; from a position that divides 3 with remainder 1; or from a position that divides 3 with remainder 2; and the same again, but reading the sequence in reverse.)

For comparison: Try writing an x86 assembly language program where the 300-byte function `doFoo()` begins at offset 0x1000... and another 200-byte function `doBar()` starts at offset 0x1001!  (I propose a name for this competition: *Are you smarter than Hepatitis B?*)

That's *hardcore* space optimisation!

**UPDATE:** Links to further info:

- [Reading Frames on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_frame) suggests Hepatitis B and "Barley Yellow Dwarf" virus (a plant virus) both overlap reading frames.
- [Hepatitis B genome info on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_B_virus#Genome).  Seems that different reading-frame subunits produce different variations of a surface protein.
- Or you could [google for "overlapping reading frames"](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=overlapping+reading+frames)
- Seems this can even happen in *mammals*!  [Extensively overlapping reading frames in a second mammalian gene](http://www.nature.com/embor/journal/v2/n9/full/embor338.html)  is a 2001 scientific paper by Marilyn Kozak that talks about a "second" gene in rat with "extensive overlapping reading frames".  (This is quite surprising as mammals have a genome structure that provides ample room for separate genes for separate proteins.)  Haven't read beyond the abstract myself.

Comment: Interesting, but I am only into bacteria, and frame shift reading never happens. Could you provide some link for this behavior ? Do you know if any non-viruses show the same technique? ORFs in bacteria normally can (rarely) overlap a couple of codons on different strands, but I am not aware of full overlap on the same strand.

Comment: @Stefano: Added a few links which I hope are helpful. Seems this even happens in *rat*! I didn't read the full paper though.

Comment: The "Tiny Teensy ELF" example listed in the OP could be considered to do this. Though its not 2 separate functions, it does in the end use the ELF header to actually contain the code as well (plus some other various information) that is usually separated out. This means that the same data is being used for multiple (3 if I read correctly) purposes (including execution!).

Comment: That's Marilyn Kozak of Kozak sequence fame. Still going, and still doing cool stuff!

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a tile-based game engine for the Apple IIgs in 65816 assembly language a few years ago.  This was a fairly slow machine and programming "on the metal" is a virtual requirement for coaxing out acceptable performance.

In order to quickly update the graphics screen one has to map the stack to the screen in order to use some special instructions that allow one to update 4 screen pixels in only 5 machine cycles.  This is nothing particularly fantastic and is described in detail in [IIgs Tech Note #70](http://www.umich.edu/~archive/apple2/technotes/tn/iigs/TN.IIGS.070). The hard-core bit was how I had to organize the code to make it flexible enough to be a general-purpose library while still maintaining maximum speed.

I decomposed the graphics screen into scan lines and created a 246 byte code buffer to insert the specialized 65816 opcodes. The 246 bytes are needed because each scan line of the graphics screen is 80 words wide and 1 additional word is required on each end for smooth scrolling.  The Push Effective Address (PEA) instruction takes up 3 bytes, so 3 * (80 + 1 + 1) = 246 bytes.

The graphics screen is rendered by jumping to an address within the 246 byte code buffer that corresponds to the right edge of the screen and patching in a BRanch Always (BRA) instruction into the code at the word immediately following the left-most word.  The BRA instruction takes a signed 8-bit offset as its argument, so it *just barely* has the range to jump out of the code buffer.

Even this isn't too terribly difficult, but the real hard-core optimization comes in here.  My graphics engine actually supported two independent background layers and animated tiles by using different 3-byte code sequences depending on the mode:

1. Background 1 uses a Push Effective Address (PEA) instruction
2. Background 2 uses a Load Indirect Indexed (LDA ($00),y) instruction followed by a push (PHA)
3. Animated tiles use a Load Direct Page Indexed (LDA $00,x) instruction followed by a push (PHA)

The critical restriction is that both of the 65816 registers (X and Y) are used to reference data and cannot be modified.  Further the direct page register (D) is set based on the origin of the second background and cannot be changed;  the data bank register is set to the data bank that holds pixel data for the second background and cannot be changed; the stack pointer (S) is mapped to graphics screen, so there is no possibility of jumping to a subroutine and returning.

Given these restrictions, I had the need to *quickly* handle cases where a word that is about to be pushed onto the stack is mixed, i.e. half comes from Background 1 and half from Background 2.  My solution was to trade memory for speed.  Because *all* of the normal registers were in use, I only had the Program Counter (PC) register to work with.  My solution was the following:

1. Define a code fragment to do the blend in the same 64K program bank as the code buffer
2. Create a copy of this code for each of the 82 words
3. There is a 1-1 correspondence, so the return from the code fragment can be a hard-coded address
4. Done! We have a hard-coded subroutine that does not affect the CPU registers.

Here is the actual code fragments

```
code_buff:   PEA $0000            ; rightmost word (16-bits = 4 pixels)
             PEA $0000            ; background 1
             PEA $0000            ; background 1
             PEA $0000            ; background 1
             LDA (72),y           ; background 2
             PHA
             LDA (70),y           ; background 2
             PHA
             JMP word_68          ; mix the data
word_68_rtn: PEA $0000            ; more background 1
             ...
             PEA $0000
             BRA *+40             ; patched exit code

             ...                  
word_68:     LDA (68),y           ; load data for background 2
             AND #$00FF           ; mask
             ORA #$AB00           ; blend with data from background 1
             PHA
             JMP word_68_rtn      ; jump back
word_66:     LDA (66),y
             ...
```

The end result was a near-optimal blitter that has minimal overhead and cranks out more than 15 frames per second at 320x200 on a 2.5 MHz CPU with a 1 MB/s memory bus.

Answer (score 5):

Michael Abrash's "[Zen of Assembly Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0673386023)" had some nifty stuff, though I admit I don't recall specifics off the top of my head.

Actually it seems like everything Abrash wrote had some nifty optimization stuff in it.

Comment: Yeah, I have the Black Book, it's pretty awesome... Pretty out of date, unfortunately.

Comment: I also have this book, don't remember the spesifics anymore.  Used to do quite some assembly earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The Stalin Scheme compiler is pretty crazy in that aspect.

Answer (score 3):

I once saw a `switch` statement with a lot of empty `case`s, a comment at the head of the switch said something along the lines of:

> Added case statements that are never hit because the compiler only turns the switch into a jump-table if there are more than N cases

I forget what N was. This was in the source code for Windows that was [leaked in 2004](http://news.cnet.com/Windows-code-up-for-grabs/2100-7349_3-5158905.html?tag=mncol;txt).

Answer (score 2):

I've gone to the Intel (or AMD) architecture references to see what instructions there are. `movsx` - move with sign extension is awesome for moving little signed values into big spaces, for example, in one instruction.

Likewise, if you know you only use 16-bit values, but you can access all of EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX , etc- then you have 8 very fast locations for values - just rotate the registers by 16 bits to access the other values.

Answer (score 1):

The [EFF DES cracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker), which used custom-built hardware to generate candidate keys (the hardware they made could prove a key isn't the solution, but could not prove a key was the solution) which were then tested with a more conventional code.

Answer (score 1):

The FSG 2.0 packer made by a Polish team, specifically made for packing executables made with assembly. If packing assembly isn't impressive enough (what's supposed to be almost as low as possible) the loader it comes with is 158 bytes and fully functional. If you try packing any assembly made .exe with something like [UPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX), it will throw a NotCompressableException at you ;)